# Computed properties on function instances

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

In knockout.js I was able to do the following:

```vue
function Person() {
    this.firstName = ko.observable('Foo')
    this.lastName = ko.observable('Bar')
    this.fullName = ko.pureComputed(() => {
        return this.firstName() + this.lastName()
    })
}

var p = new Person()
console.log(p.fullName()) // FooBar
```

Is there any way to add reactive computed properties on objects *which are not a component data* in Vue?

Comment: Have you tried `computed` property in Vue.js?

Comment: @MuthuKumaran I am aware of computed properties on components. Can I create them on plain objects too?

Comment: Why? What is it you're trying to accomplish? Seeing as Vue is only really concerned with its own lifecycle and properties, I think it's unlikely **it** will offer this functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Vue, you do not need to explicitly declare reactive properties and methods like Knockout requires. Everything is just a plain object.

What actually makes the object reactive in Vue is when you assign it to a component through a property that was declared in the `data` object of that component.

So your example in Vue would just be:

```js
function Person() {
  this.firstName = 'Foo';
  this.lastName = 'Bar';
  this.fullName = function () {
    return this.firstName + this.lastName;
  };
}

var p = new Person();
console.log(p.fullName());  // FooBar
```

If you use it inside a component, then it will be reactive, like this:

```js
const comp = new Vue({
  template: '<div>{{ person.fullName() }}</div>',
  data: {
    person: null,
  },
});

// Vue detects that p is being assigned to the reactive property
// 'person' and makes p reactive.
comp.person = p;
```

I should mention, I'm not really sure what you mean by "which are not a component data in Vue" because the whole reason why you want something to be reactive in the first place is because you want it to be rendered in a component's template and for the component to re-render automatically when a property changes, so you can't really make something reactive externally to Vue.

I understood your question as along the lines of "how do I make something reactive to Vue without needing to specify it directly within a Vue component's data or computed properties?". Keep in mind that the `person` property *must be declared upfront in the component's `data`* for that property (and any data assigned to it) to be reactive. As long as you do that, then you can design your model objects however you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Let me elaborate. I have a list of entities from the database that I store in Vuex. I know that if I alter a property using `Vue.set` it triggers the dependency detection / reactivity. However, as far as I can tell, there is no way to add a computed property to the entity, e.g. `FullName`, and make it reactive. Or am I missing something?

Comment: You can either add a `FullName` method to each object, or define a getter property with [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty).